# unix how to find the space occupied

Tags: unix, terminal

In unix how to find the space occupied ( in Bytes) by the /home directory including all its subdirectories.

The du command outputs the number of  **kilobyes** used by each subdirectory. Useful if you have gone over quota and you want to find out which directory has the most files. but how shuld i use tat in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du -bs ~` will print out total space *in bytes* used in your home directory and all of its sub-directories, though you may find `du -hs` to print friendlier numbers.

See also `man du`

(also probably a serverfault.com or superuser.com question)

Comment: @unhillbilly: OP said "/home directory including all its subdirectories"

Comment: `-s` means "including all subdirectories".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
du --bytes /home
```

If you really just want the number:

```
du --bytes -s /home|cut -f 1
```

Comment: If you really want just the number, don't you use `du --bytes -s /home`?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: You will still need to `cut`, but yes, the tail was unnecessary. removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't use the command line, I like to use [KDirStat](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/) to see the usage of space.  I'm just a visual guy.